# Django unit test for function

Tags: django, unit-testing

I need to test if a user is active.  I have that function:

Service.py

```
@validate_input({
    'code': {'required': True}
})
def signup_complete(self, data):
    try:
        code = VerificationCode.objects.select_related('user').get(code=data["code"],
                                                                   code_type="registration",
                                                                   expiration_date__gt=timezone.now())
    except VerificationCode.DoesNotExist:
        raise NotFound(_(u"Неверный код восстановленыя"), 1001)
    user = code.user
    user.is_active = True
    user.save()
    code.delete()
```

and I try to write a test for this function, but I don't know what argument I need to send.

Test.py

```
def test_signup_complete(self):
    user = SiteUser.objects.get(email="Test@gmail.com")
    code = VerificationCode.objects.get_or_create(user=user, code_type="registration", code=user.code)
    UserService(user).signup_complete()

    self.assertEqual(user.is_active, True)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can reproduce all the steps needed for user registration and activation. Accessing registration page, sending filled form, checking emails with activation code etc. With this approach (which is much more reliable in comparison to your current code) you can get the confirmation code in the same way as real user gets it (for example, from profile activation email).

Comment: i made user registration test and it pass now i need to activate user